# Проблема со сменой слайда

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider

При нажатия на кнопку смены слайда(любую),в первый раз всё работает отлично, дальше 
происходит странная вещь , чтобы её увидеть вот код

```js
$('.next').click(function() {
  var firstImg = $('.first');
  var firstImgIndex = $('.first').index();
  var nextImageIndex = firstImgIndex + 1;
  var nextImage = $('.img').eq(nextImageIndex);

  firstImg.fadeOut(800);
  firstImg.removeClass('first');
  if (nextImageIndex == ($('.img:last').index() + 1)) {
    $('.img').eq(0).fadeIn(800);
    $('.img').eq(0).addClass('first');
  } else {
    nextImage.fadeIn(800);
    nextImage.addClass('first');
  }
});

$('.prev').click(function() {
  var firstImg = $('.first');
  var firstImgIndex = $('.first').index();
  var prevImageIndex = firstImgIndex - 1;
  var prevImage = $('.img').eq(prevImageIndex);

  firstImg.fadeOut(800);
  firstImg.removeClass('first');
  prevImage.fadeIn(800);
  prevImage.addClass('first');
});
```

```css
.content__work {
  height: 80%;
  width: 70%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 1fr 100px;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.slider li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.btn__slider {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  background: #000000;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.btn__slider:hover {
  color: #DBDBDB;
}

img {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.first {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>JQUERY</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="content__work">
    <button class="prev btn__slider"> < </button>
    <div class="slider">
      <img src="img/slide1.jpg" class="img first">
      <img src="img/slide2.jpg" class="img">
      <img src="img/slide3.jpg" class="img">
    </div>
    <button class="next btn__slider"> > </button>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Картинки вытесняют друг друга, из-за этого возникает такой эффект. Можно решить с помощью CSS:

```js
$('.next').click(function() {
  var firstImg = $('.first');
  var firstImgIndex = $('.first').index();
  var nextImageIndex = firstImgIndex + 1;
  var nextImage = $('.img').eq(nextImageIndex);

  firstImg.fadeOut(800);
  firstImg.removeClass('first');
  if (nextImageIndex == ($('.img:last').index() + 1)) {
    $('.img').eq(0).fadeIn(800);
    $('.img').eq(0).addClass('first');
  } else {
    nextImage.fadeIn(800);
    nextImage.addClass('first');
  }
});

$('.prev').click(function() {
  var firstImg = $('.first');
  var firstImgIndex = $('.first').index();
  var prevImageIndex = firstImgIndex - 1;
  var prevImage = $('.img').eq(prevImageIndex);

  firstImg.fadeOut(800);
  firstImg.removeClass('first');
  prevImage.fadeIn(800);
  prevImage.addClass('first');
});
```

```css
.content__work {
  height: 80%;
  width: 70%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 1fr 100px;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vw;
}

.slider li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.btn__slider {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  background: #000000;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.btn__slider:hover {
  color: #DBDBDB;
}

img {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: absolute;
}

.first {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>JQUERY</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="content__work">
    <button class="prev btn__slider"> < </button>
    <div class="slider">
      <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/20.jpg" class="img first">
      <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/21.jpg" class="img">
      <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/22.jpg" class="img">
    </div>
    <button class="next btn__slider"> > </button>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: А можете сказать почему при первом нажатие происходит резкая анимация, а потом как написано в коде?

Comment: @NikitaPerminov потому что резко убирается класс first. Чтобы избавиться от этого используйте колбэк fadeOut и в нем убирайте класс уже после того, как элемент исчезнет: 
firstImg.fadeOut(800,function(){firstImg.removeClass('first');});